# Form validation with alerts and out that displays all checked items

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've finally been able to validate my radio button and check box. However, I still have some minor issues.

Issues 1:

When I submit my form after filling all the required information, the form outputs all the selected information and yet I notice that when I select multiple check boxes it only displays one in the output summary. Any tips on how to get the other selected check box item to appear for example If I check 2 Items I should see two checked items in the output summary page

Issue 2: The form validation

For each text field, radio box, and check box that is not selected, meaning if I were to fill all but one of the text and submit the form without selecting a radio box and check box, I should receive an alert stating what is missing. However, the alerts ends after step 1 one after the email. it doesn't even alert if no radio box and check box is selected unless I hit submit to validate the form again.

How do I force the from to check for validation from step 1 to 3?

My main concern is to be able to validate the check box and be able to select multiple and have my selection appear in the out put.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Hello and JavaScript</title>
<script>

function doClear()/*This function clears the order form once it has been completed*/
{
document.PizzaForm.customer.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.state.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.zip.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.phone.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.email.value = "";

document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;

document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;
return;
}

function doSubmit() /*This function submits the order form once it has been completed*/

{
if (validateText()==false)
   {
   alert("Required data missing in Step 1");
   }

if (validateRadio()==false)
   {
   alert("Required data missing in Step 2");
   }

if(validateTops()==false)
   {
   alert("Required data missing in Step 3");
   return;
   }

/*This alerts tells the order form is complete and it will list all the customer information such as Name address etc.*/
var OrderWindow
OrderWindow = window.open("","","status,height=500,width=500");
OrderWindow.focus();
with (OrderWindow.document)

{
write("<h1><center>Customer Order Summary</center></h1><p>")
write("Name:" + document.PizzaForm.customer.value + "<br>")
write("Address:" + document.PizzaForm.address.value + "<br>")
write("City:" + document.PizzaForm.city.value + "<br>")
write("State:" + document.PizzaForm.state.value + "<br>")
write("Zip Code:" + document.PizzaForm.zip.value + "<br>")
write("Phone Number:" + document.PizzaForm.phone.value + "<br>")
write("E-Mail:" + document.PizzaForm.email.value + "<br>")
write("Pizza Size:" + validateRadio() + "<br>")
write("Pizza Toppings:" + validateTops() + "<br>")
write("<h3><center>Thank You for your Order.</center></h3><p>")
}
return;
}

function validateText()/*This function validate all the text field in step 1.*/

{
 if (document.PizzaForm.customer.value == "")
 {
   alert("Please provide your name");
   document.PizzaForm.customer.focus();

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.address.value == "")
 {
   alert("Please provide your address.");
   document.PizzaForm.address.focus();

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.city.value == "")
{
   alert("Please provide your City.");

}

if (document.PizzaForm.state.value == "")
{
   alert("Please provide your State.");

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.zip.value == "" ||
   isNaN( document.PizzaForm.zip.value ) ||
   document.PizzaForm.zip.value.length != 5 )
 {
   alert("Please provide your Zip code.");
   document.PizzaForm.zip.focus() ;

 }

if (!/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(document.PizzaForm.phone.value)) {
    alert("Please provide a correct phone number.");
    document.PizzaForm.phone.focus();
 }

var emailID = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
 {
   alert("Please enter correct Email.")
   document.myForm.Email.focus() ;

 }
 return (true);
}

function validateRadio()/*This function validates the radio selection*/
{
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.sizes.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].checked)
        return document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].value;
    alert("Please choose a pizza size.");
    return false;
}

function validateTops()/*This function validates the checkbox selection*/
{
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked==true) 
        return document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
    alert("Please pick a topping of your choice.");
    return false;
}



</s cript>

</ head> 
<body>
<form Name ="PizzaForm">
<h1> The JavaScrpt Pizza Parlor</h>
<p>
<h4> Step 1: Enter your name, address, phone number, and email:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address:&nbsp;<Input name="address" size="50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="city" size="15"type="text">
State:<Input name="state" size="2"type="text"><br>
Zip:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="zip" size="5"type="text"><br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="phone" size="50"type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="email" size="31"type="text"><br>
</ font>
</ p>
<p>
<h4> Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</ font>
</ p>
<p>
<h4> Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Plain">Plain
</ font>
</ p>
<!--
========================================================
The submit and clear form  buttons belows.
========================================================
-->
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
</ form>
</ body>
</ html>
```

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: I guess you have a lot going on. Are you sure you cannot use jQuery? It would surely simplify some of your code (imao). And about the multiple selection, how do you want it to be shown? Can it be a comma separated list? (like `'Pepperoni', 'Black Olives', 'Extra Cheese'`, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will try to solve what I got from your description:

Issue #1: When you state a `return` from within a function, you end it's execution. So, on your `validateTops()`, you pretty much end it when you find the first topping. Here's an alternative approach:

```
function validateTops()/*This function validates the checkbox selection*/
{
    var toppings = []; //<== empty array
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked==true) 
            toppings.push(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value); //<== including on the array

    if (toppings.length == 0) { //<== testing if array is empty, meaning 'no tops'
        alert("Please pick a topping of your choice."); 
        return false;
    } else { return toppings; }
}
```

I didn't quite get your other issues, but I think it has something to do with alerting about steps that were missing during you validations, right? So here's something else:

```
var stepsMissing = []; //<== new empty array
if (validateText()==false) {
    stepsMissing.push('Step 1');
}
if (validateRadio()==false) {
    stepsMissing.push('Step 2');
}
if(!(validateTops())) { //<==same as "validateTops() == false", just so you know...
    stepsMissing.push('Step 3');
}
if (stepsMissing.length > 0) {
    alert('Requiring data missing in '+stepsMissing); //<== this is turning your validation message into one message. For keeping it separated in 3 alerts, you can use a for loop iterating through stepsMissing
}
```

One other thing: you are calling your validate functions once, to do the validations, and then you are calling it again to fullfill you "order form". Shouldn't you just call it once and store the returning values on local vars, so you would test them and then use them on the final order form? I know that those functions are something too simple, but you just don't waste executions of the same thing like that.

By the way: If you could use jQuery, you could implement this with lot less code, and in a much more readable way (imao).